# How to hide part of the game object when viewed through another invisible game object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, augmented-reality, mask

I had the following problem. I need to hide part of the game object while viewing through another invisible game object. In theory, this should work as follows (as shown in the pictures below).

[part of the AR-hat hides behind the head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMJjJ.png)

[but when viewed through the AR-hat, this part should not be transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqS5c.png)

But in practice, when using the following stencil shader for AR-head:

```
Shader "Custom/Stencil/Mask OneZLess"
{
SubShader
{
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue"="Geometry-1" }
    ColorMask 0
    ZWrite off

    Stencil
    {
        Ref 1
        Comp always
        Pass replace
    }

    Pass
    {
        Cull Back
        ZTest Less

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
        };
        struct v2f
        {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        };
        v2f vert(appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            return o;
        }
        half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
        {
            return half4(1,1,0,1);
        }

        ENDCG
    }
} 
}
```

And the next shader for the AR-hat:

```
Shader "Custom/Stencil/Diffuse NotEqualOne"
{

    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue"="Geometry" }
        LOD 200

        Stencil
        {
            Ref 1
            Comp notequal
            Pass keep
        }

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        fixed4 _Color;

        struct Input
        {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
        {
            fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }

        ENDCG
    }

Fallback "VertexLit"
}
```

The scene is as follows (as in the picture):

[The hat is always transparent when it crosses with the head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzCbI.png)

Maybe someone will help me (who has experience in working with shaders), how to make the AR-hat become transparent only when viewed through the AR-head. And if we look at the AR-head through the AR-hat, then nothing should happen.

I apologize for the confusing statement of the question, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something here, but why do you think you need stencil buffer here? It seems like there is nothing so tricky that normal Z-sorting couldn't handle.

Comment: @PhilMcLaren thanks for answer! you're right. I solved the problem using depth mask shader and render queue.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution as an answer? I'd like to see what you did.

Answer (score -1):

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/DepthMask

I think this is the way you mentioned finding. Putting it here for anyone searching in future like me.

Just make sure not to use the Geometry values which yields 2000 and use the provided values in the article(3000).